# The CORS gives me an error when I connect to it from a outside program

Tags: c#, node.js, api, cors

I'm having a problem with the request to my API from my program in C#,
it's giving me a CORS error (From the web it works because my local IP it's in the whitelist, but from the program it gives me an error the cors request).

The api is created in Express.

My Cors:

```
const dominiosPermitidos = [url];
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
        console.log(origin);
        
        if (dominiosPermitidos.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            //El origen del request esta permitido
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('No permitido por Cors'))
        }
    }
}    

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

The call in c#:

```
url = "127.0.0.1/api/datos";
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream myStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myStream);
//Leemos los datos
string Datos = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myStreamReader.ReadToEnd());

dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Datos);

return data;
```

Error c#
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQwD0.png)

Error api
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giD7p.png)

Should I deactivate Cors?

Thanks

I tried to put my local ip in the whitelist, but when i call the API from my C# program the CORS gives me an error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I just updated the question and attached 2 pictures with the errors in C# and NodeJS.
@viveknuna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# program doesn't seem to be sending an origin, which is fine since it's not a browser. But since your server is configured to error early if CORS is going to block the response from reaching the browser, you're getting an error back from it (which you normally wouldn't be able to read if it was from a browser).

If you look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors in the section "Configuring CORS w/ Dynamic Origin", you'll see that they put a " || !origin" in the second example for this very reason, so the server continues processing it if it's from a server. So you should be able to just change your Node.js server code like this:

```js
const dominiosPermitidos = [url];
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
        console.log(origin);
        
        if (dominiosPermitidos.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || (! origin)) {
            //El origen del request esta permitido
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('No permitido por Cors'))
        }
    }
}    

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

You might also find this helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: since I can't write comments I'll have to do it here. You could disable CORS on the server, but that will mean your website on that other origin won't be able to send requests. But I might have misunderstood and you might not ever be sending requests to the API from the browser, in which case you can just remove all the CORS logic.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem completely, but I have a question, if I put the !origin, could it be a security error?

Comment: No, it would be completely safe not to have any CORS related checks or logic on the server. The issue is that you need to have a bit of logic if you want the browser to be able to interact with the server (unless the server is hosting the current page, which simplifies things).

If you're curious, I'd suggest having a look at the mdn link, but I'll give a quick explanation of what CORS does...

Say you're on using your browser to visit evil.com, you don't want it to be able to make requests to bank.com and impersonate you. So browsers will stop the requests unless bank.com allows it.

Comment: But servers don't have this restriction as they have more control over what cookies they send, and you'd be able to get around them all anyway since it's not running in the browser so it has greater privileges. The early error doesn't improve the security as anyone could easily get around it if they wanted to, it's just so the server doesn't bother processing a request the client will never see. If you wanted to restrict who can access this API, you'd have an API key system in addition to properly configured CORS (i.e not just allowing every origin).